# List item `li:hover` is not working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code below? I'm trying to make the menu show the list when hover over each link, but it's not working for some reason. I have already tried `.menu ul ul: hover {visibility: visible; }` and it didn't work.

Check my code and thank you in advance.

```css
  .menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #222;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.menu a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">test5</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">test6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test8</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">test9</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What elements should be shown when what menu items are hovered over? `test2` should show `test3` and `test4`, correct? Along with `test5` showing `test6`, `test7` and `test8`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have slightly modified your code. Sub-nav `UL` are now nested within the required `LI`. When you hover over "test2" nav it will show the sub-nav.

The CSS line below was modified too. Instead of using `:hover` on the sub-nav `UL` the code will now target the `LI` with the sub-nav and display the required one.

```
.menu ul li ul:hover {
```

to

```
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
 .menu{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-color:#222;
 font-family:'Arial';

 }
 .menu ul{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 }
 .menu ul li{
  width:150px;
  float:left;

 }
  .menu a{
  padding:15px;
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#222;
  color:#fff;
  }
  .menu ul ul{
   position:absolute;
   visibility:hidden;

    }
    
   /*CSS modified here: when you hover over LI with sub-nav, it will display the UL in it.*/
   .menu ul li:hover > ul{
    visibility:visible;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
     }
    .menu a:hover{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    color:#fff;
     }
```

```html
<body> 
  <nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test2</a>
      
      <!-- nested UL in LI -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">test5</a>
      <!-- nested UL in LI -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">test6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test8</a></li>
      </ul>   
    </li>    
    <li><a href="#">test9</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```